# interconnecting 2 android emulators on different machines

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there a way to interconnect 2 emulator instances running on different machines? One of them is acting as a client and other as a server, hence 2-way interaction is required.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, should be possible, but apparently you need to prepare some port forwarding.

Check here:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: that only talks about interconnecting emulators on the same machine.